# How to scrape a website using curl with proper indentation of html elements

Tags: javascript, php, curl, web-scraping

As question states, I use CURl for web-scraping and I get a response which include all html elements but are not in proper indentation.

```
curl somewebsite.com/somepage > scrape.html/scrape.txt
```

after this command the data gets saved in **scrape.txt** or **scrape.html** file the contents looks very messy and mostly its in 1 line only.

The content of the file looks lke this

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><script src="/cdn-cgi/apps/head/a2ff1ftsK3yTu21p1BeEN2BZsnA.js"></script><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@400;700&amp;family=DM+Sans:wght@400&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet" media="print" onload="if(!window._isAppPrerendering)this.removeAttribute(&quot;media&quot;);"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@400;700&amp;family=DM+Sans:wght@400&amp;display=swap" rel="preload" as="style"><link href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" rel="preconnect" crossorigin="true"><meta charset="utf-8">
```

as u see above it's all in 1 line and it goes off till < /html>

Is there any technique in curl or any other easy way to get output of a scraped webpage with indentation followed?

I am OK with solution in PHP, javascript, or NodeJS

Thank you in advance.....

Comment: How do you view this file?

Comment: Using command prompt or linux terminal you can save the scraped website in a file and after opening that file you see that content.

Comment: A decent text editor with HTML support could probably pretty-print it for you. There are even web based tools like https://jsonformatter.org/html-pretty-print

Comment: @ADyson that tool is pretty nice as it does the scraping as well as beautifying, not the best but at least better than having a 1 line code, thank you so much, I think this might be answer for my question.

Comment: Curl does not compress or reformat the HTML you get in the response. You're basically asking for recommendation about tools to format / beautify / pretty-print HTML which, I'm afraid, is explicitly off-topic in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find solution for the problem no one answered either.

My solution is to use some beautifying tools like

https://beautifytools.com/html-beautifier.php#

This tool is actually good for large websites with large script and styles.

Answer (score 0):

> curl somewebsite.com/somepage | php -r '$d=new DOMDocument();$d->preserveWhiteSpace=false;$d->formatOutput=true;@$d->loadHTML(stream_get_contents(STDIN), LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_NOBLANKS);echo $d->saveXML();' > scrape.html/scrape.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/) - the granddaddy of html tools. Install it then pipe the `curl` output to it.

```
sudo apt install tidy
```

then

```
curl http://www.example.com | tidy
```

This should be able to give a tidy html code with tags inline.